# Unable to add new/local folder to Repo

Tags: git

I cloned a repo my local :

C:\cloned-repo

I then added a new folder with script to my local cloned-repo

c:\cloned-repo\Utils....

I need to check this new folder back to the origin

Doing :

```
cd Utils\
git add .
git commit 
git commit -m "message" --all
git push
```

doesn't do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Was there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands:

```
git add . //this will add all changed files
git commit -m "commit message" // committing the changes
git push -u remoteName(should be origin) remoteBranchName(like master, or branch that you created)
```

Answer (score 0):

Git don't store directories itselfs, so when you add first file in this directory, directory should be created in repo too.